# Importing JSON to data and labels for chart.js

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, chart.js

I have a basic javascript application that should import a json file in the form of:

```
[{
"name": "John",
"group": "Schools",
"amount": "850"
},

{
"name": "Martin",
"group": "Private Students",
"amount": "10050"
}]
```

and use it alongside chart.js, using the 'group' part as the labels, and adding to the data by the 'amount' part respectively. Can anyone help? I got it working with fixed values, but cannot seem to import and parse through the file correctly

The main file looks like this so far, with the label being undefined as of yet:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="moneyFile.json"></script>
<head>
  <title>Money Thingy</title>
</head>
<body>
  <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
  <script>
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');

   //  $.getJSON("moneyFile.json", function(data) {
   //   var labels = [];
   //   var data = [];
   //
   //   $.each( data, function( group, amount ) {
   //     labels.push(group);
   //     data.push(amount);
   //   });
   // }

   // var data = jQuery.getJSON("moneyFile.json");
   // console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));

   var data = JSON.parse(moneyFile);
   console.log(data[0]);

    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
          labels: labels,
          datasets: [{
              label: 'Money in',
              // data:
              backgroundColor: [
                  'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)'
              ],
              borderColor: [
                  'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                  'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                  'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                  'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                  'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
              ],
              borderWidth: 1
          }]
      },
      options: {
          scales: {
              yAxes: [{
                  ticks: {
                      beginAtZero:true
                  }
              }]
          }
      }
    });
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any errors in console ?

Comment: Where is `moneyFile` defined? you'll need to get the data frm `moneyFile.json` using AJAX (`XMLHttpRequest`, `fetch`, or (if you must), you could use `jQuery.getJSON`)

Answer (score -1):

You need to map your data to required format. CartJs requires `data` parameter which is in this format `data: [{x:'2016-12-25', y:20}, {x:'2016-12-26', y:10}]` so you can do something

```
data: jsonData.map(item => ({x: item.group, y: Number(item.amount)}));
```